# Using basis $e=[x^3,x^2,x,1]$ instead of $e=[1,x,x^2,x^3]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

So on an exam I've got zero points on the question (and sub-questions) to find matrix of linear operator $L:\Bbb{R}^4[x]\to \Bbb{R}^4[x]$ given by $L(p(x)) = p(x)+xp(2)$ with respect to canonical basis $e$

I've said I'm using notation $(a,b,c,d)$ to mean $(ax^3,bx^2,cx,d)$
I've found the matrix for $L$ lets say $A$ which is
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\8 & 4 & 3 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Now
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\8 & 4 & 3 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ 8a+4b+3c+d \\ d\end{bmatrix}$$
Which is the right result (using my notation), however they've got a different matrix by using $(a,b,c,d) = (a,bx,cx^2,dx^3)$ They found
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 3 & 4 & 8\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Which is again the right answer (using their notation), so I'm looking for references to use of the first notation or references/reasons to why my notation is wrong.

Comment: In my opinion your answer is right. You should talk with your professor. Maybe he didn't notice that you wer using a different basis.He saw a different matrix and cross you the exercise.

Comment: @Dog_69 Glad to hear, I've talked to one professor which turned me down so now I'm intending to send an email to my professor but I'd thought of finding some kind of references before and to check if I'm right.

Comment: Can you post the subject of your exam ? At least the problematic part ?

Comment: @nicomezi Sure, but can you clarify what do you mean by subject of your exam?(English is not my native language)

Comment: It is not mine either, may be the problem is on my part. By subject I mean the text of your exam.

Comment: As my Linear Algebra professor used to say "When I see someone strange, I first ask what basis he is using, so we can talk the same language."

Comment: "I'm using notation $(a,b,c,d)$ to mean $(ax^3,bx^2,cx,d)$" doesn't make sense. You want to say, $(a,b,c,d)$ to denote $ax^2+bx^2+cx+d$. An other question is : does $1$ refer to the vector $(1,0,0,0)$ or $(0,0,0,1)$ ? Because  to use the basis $\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$ for $\{(0,0,0,1), (0,0,1,0), (0,1,0,0), (1,0,0,0)\}$ is correct, but for $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$ is not correct. Seeing what you've done, it looks that you used the second basis, which is not correct.

Comment: People doing  in "non-standard" way, have many times changed the world, but .. always had lot of troubles !

Comment: @Surb your last sentence does not make sense. Since a set is not ordered, the last two sets in your answer are the same. This is why the question headline uses square brackets for the basis.

Comment: If you  stated on your written answer on the exam what  you have written here then your answer was correct.  A vector-space basis has no intrinsic order on its members. It is  merely a   maximal linearly-independent $set.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **First :** "I'm using notation $(a,b,c,d)$ to mean $(ax^3,bx^2,cx,d)$" doesn't make any sense. You wanted to say, "I'm using the notation $(a,b,c,d)$ to denote $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$".
- **Secondly :** In your notation, does for example $x$ refer to the vector $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ or to the vector $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$  ? Because  to use the basis $\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$ for $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ is correct, but using $\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$ for $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ is conventionally not correct but makes sense with your notation (and it's what you seem to have made).

But your work didn't deserve 0 mark. In my opinion, you deserve almost all points for this question (since you precise that $(a,b,c,d)$ refer to $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$). Strange that you got 0 mark !

Comment: Could the downvoter explain ?

Comment: I didn't downvote. For me it's indeed a reason for the OP marks, but why can't we say that for example $x$ refer to $(0,0,1,0)^T$ ?

Comment: @MSE: Your question sounds like "why $(2,3,4,1)$ and $(0,0,9,6)$ are not the same vector ?".  If you have in mind $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$ for $\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$ of course your calculation will be correct and you'll be able to conclude right things. But unfortunately, they are not conventional notation.

Answer (score 6):

It makes no sense to ask what is the matrix of a linear transformation without fixing bases. If the person to whom this question is being asked is free to choose those bases, then both answers are correct.

Comment: The question asked for matrix using the canonical basis $e$ but didn't specify what $e$ is. I didn't see that till now (I'll add this to the question) though they didn't specify what canonical basis $e$.

Comment: @kingW3 The canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ is $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}$.

Comment: You may even choose a basis where the map’s matrix is the identity.

Comment: Oh I guess I'm wrong then, I've thought that $\{x^{n-1},x^{n-2},\ldots,x^2,x,1\}$ is a canonical basis. Do you by any chance have any references on the definition of a canonical basis?

Comment: @kingW3 See the first lines of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_basis).

Comment: @MichaelHoppe You need two bases for that.

Answer (score 1):

If $\bf J$ denotes the [Exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix)
$$
{\bf J} = {\bf J}^T  = {\bf J}^{\, - 1}  = \left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
then
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   {x^{\,3} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,2} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,1} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,0} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = {\bf J}\left( {\matrix{
   {x^{\,0} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,1} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,2} }  \cr 
   {x^{\,3} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
and between the matrix you have found and the expected one there is a *change of basis* relation
$$
{\bf A} = {\bf J}\,{\bf A'}\;{\bf J} = {\bf J}\,{\bf A'}\;{\bf J}^{\,{\bf  - 1}}  = {\bf J}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} \,{\bf A'}\;{\bf J}
$$

So, if you have specified the base you were considering, your answer is right and shall be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers so far are missing a key point: the exam question as you’ve presented it here requires you to use the “canonical basis.” That’s a very specific requirement. If the basis that you chose to use was different—remember that these are *ordered* bases, so the same vectors in a different order is a different basis—then you did not answer the question correctly. Outside references to support your approach are pretty much irrelevant, I think. What matters for this particular exam is the definition of “canonical basis” that was used *in that course*.

For my part, I would’ve given you partial credit instead of a zero for working through a solution, but you did fail to answer the specific question that you were given.